# Why is my pc booting in recovery mode?

Tags: data-recovery, recovery-mode

My computer currently will only boot into *recovery mode* while it was fine the last time I used it.  I ran `journalctl -xb` and in red it says

> Failed to mount /media/cdrom/auto.  (It says this twice)
>   Name server cannot be used: temporary failure in name resolution (-3)

I am a bit lost on what to do as I have only ever used linux before on my *Raspberry PI*...
so if anyone could help I would be very grateful.

Comment: This `/media/cdrom/auto` is the problem it's trying to mount something there but can't so what do you have in your `/etc/fstab` that needs to be mounted at boot, comment out that line in the `/etc/fstab` and it should boot

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply, I'm not great with the command line, so I dont know where to comment out the line, as when I use the journalctl -xb command it doesn't let me edit anything, and I don't know how to find /etc/fstab without using a gui.  I don't know if this is doing the right thing but I tried cd /etc/fstab and it said it wasn't a directory

Comment: When editing if not sure please try and copy that file and add to your question so I can take a look at what's in there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please kindly and strictly follow these steps:

1. Boot computer into `recovery mode`
2. At the recovery mode type the following to mount your filesystem in read/write mode:

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   ```

   - **WARNING DON'T IGNORE SPACES, COPY AND PASTE IF YOU MUST**
3. Then get to the `/etc/fstab` for editing with:

   1. `nano /etc/fstab`
   2. Comment out any line with the mount instructions for directory `/media` by adding the `#` character at the beginning of that line
   3. After the edit use the following commands to save and close the `nano` editor

      - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
      - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>
   4. Now reboot the system.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Great it worked out...